# Remember suchThat clauses when shrinking

Tags: scala, scalacheck

If I have a custom generator then the shrinker will remember my `suchThat` clause and not shrink with invalid values:

```
val myGen = Gen.identifier.suchThat { _.length > 3 }

// all shrinks have > 3 characters
property("failing case") = forAll (myGen) { (a: String) =>
  println(s"Gen suchThat Value: $a")
  a == "Impossible"
}
```

If I do something further to the generated value (ie map it) then the shrinker "forgets" my suchThat clause:

```
// the shrinker will shrink all the way down to ""
property("failing case") = forAll (myGen.map{_ + "bbb"}) { (a: String) =>
    println(s"Gen with map Value: $a")
    a == "Impossible"
}
```

Is it possible to have suchThat values propagate through generators. In my real project I am doing more than a simple map but that seems to be the simplest example of the limitation I am hitting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the answer is no (at least at this point in time).

This is quite annoying although perhaps not as trivial as it seems. The generator result does attempt to keep track of the sieve although it gets lost in `map` and `flatMap`. Apart from applying the sieve to the result of the shrink there isn't any other connection back to the generator. Even if there were all the intermediate results would need to be retained and applied to each sieve at the correct points. That then raises the question of: What exactly is being shrunk? The generated result or the original generator(s)?

The only solution that I have found so far is to either:

- Disable shrinking, or
- Implement a custom `Shrink`, or
- Add a `whenever` clause that rechecks the generated value.

This can be quite challenging, especially when composing multiple generators.